# Error installing capybara-webkit on win7 x86 machine

Tags: ruby, installation, capybara-webkit

I've got a problem with installing capybara-webkit.
When I try 
**gem install capybara-webkit** the following error occurs

ERROR:  Error installing capybara-webkit:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb

ruby v 1.9.3 p194, qt 4.7.4 (also tried with 4.8)

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've fixed it by downloading the latest sources from github and compiling the gem manually.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding Qt's bin directory to path. And don't forget to install [QT 4.7 OpenSource edition](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp) (with support for mingw32). if not done so.

Comment: Yeah, I've already added QT bin directory to xPath and I have qt-win-opensource-4.7.4-mingw.exe that is the only QT I have installer. Do I have to install smth else like QT sdk?